# How to convert the content of an Image to text in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, nvarchar

I'm querying a database and payload data is stored in an image column in Microsoft SQL Server 2019.
I want to read the actual text value of this column.

I wrote following query:

`SELECT CAST(PAYLOAD AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM MY_TABLE`

It gave me the error:
**Explicit conversion from data type image to nvarchar(max) is not allowed.**

It doesn't seem to work and I'm looking for a way to convert this value to a text in a select query.

Comment: `image` is effectively `varbinary(max)` but we don't know the encoding. Is it ANSI or UTF-16, and if the former which code page?

Comment: Are you still using the `image` data type? That's been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 was a thing. Ref: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql)

Comment: please add Structure table  and expected (only you want cast )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double conversion:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), PAYLOAD)) AS PAYLOAD_TEXT 
FROM MY_TABLE
```

The whole example:

```
-- Create sample database
CREATE DATABASE img
GO

-- Create sample table with image type
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
PAYLOAD IMAGE
)
GO

-- An example value as image
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(PAYLOAD)
VALUES(0xFF)
GO

--Resolution for your problem
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), PAYLOAD)) AS PAYLOAD_TEXT 
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Note: Image type is deprecated.

Comment: That''s assuming the original was UTF-16 of course, otherwise you need `varchar`